# Weapon modifiers before/after a weapon's title in a stat block: where do they come from, and how are they used?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, npc

Where are these modifiers before and after a weapon's title on a stat block coming from? Also, how are these used when rolling for an attack?

> Melee ***+1** dagger* **+10** (1d4+4 plus poison), or ***+1** dagger* **+8** (1d4+4 plus poison)

[Dagger Fighter](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/npc-s/npcs-cr-7/dagger-fighter/)

To give some context, I've been working on my own NPC's stat block and couldn't find a good explanation of where those modifiers were coming from in the books.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. There's no way to know where those modifiers are coming from without a link to the original text where you got it from. They vary from creature to creature. Which creature are you interested in? Anyway, thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: "+1 dagger" is the name of the item, and it refers to a dagger with a +1 enhancement bonus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Below is the entirety of the Melee entry for the NPC in question:

> Melee **+1** dagger *+10* (1d4+4 plus poison), or +1 dagger +8 (1d4+4 plus poison) and masterwork dagger +7 (1d4+1 plus poison)

When looking at a weapon entry, the first number (bolded above) prior to the weapon's name is usually the weapon's enhancement bonus. You don't take this number into account when rolling for an attack - its just for your reference. The second number (italicized above) is the total attack bonus for that particular attack. That would be what you add to your die roll to determine if the attack hits.

As for where these modifiers are coming from, they are calculated based on the creature's statistics, just as they would be for a player character. For this NPC, it has a +5 base attack bonus, +3 strength modifier, weapon focus with daggers for a +1 and a +1 enhancement bonus on its dagger, for a total of +10.

This particular stat block also provides an alternative option when attacking, signified by the "or". It lists two attacks, one with a +1 dagger and the other with a masterwork dagger. Since these have lower attack bonus and they're listed separated by an "and" you can determine that they're the NPCs attacks when two-weapon-fighting (you can also guess this from its feat list lower in the stat block). When full attacking, the creature can make one attack with its +1 dagger (at a +8 bonus) and one attack with its masterwork dagger (at a +7 bonus).

Note that the stat block has an error and the masterwork dagger's attack bonus should be 1 point higher each time it shows up.

Comment: This answer is wrong, this is not a full attack as the BAB is only 5, and to get the second iterative attack requires a BAB of 6+. Its clearly using the TWF feat.

Comment: Two weapon fighting is a full attack, even if you don't make any iterative attacks because your BAB is not high enough. This is the case here.

Comment: Yes, the TWF is a type of full attack, but since there is a specific type of full attack compared to the TWF one, you should make mention of that.

Answer (score 3):

#### The Weapon Stat Block is a convenient shorthand for the DM

Rather than having to calculate the attack bonus for each attack each round, you simply roll and add the number next to the attack you want to make. Now to break down your example from the dagger fighter:

> Melee +1 dagger +10 (1d4+4 plus poison), or +1 dagger +8 (1d4+4 plus poison) and masterwork dagger +7 (1d4+1 plus poison)

This means that the dagger fighter has two options. They can make one attack with their +1 dagger at a +10 to hit and dealing (1d4+4 plus poison). To get to this attack bonus we need to look at their stat sheet. They have +3 from strength, +3 bab from rogue, +2 bab from fighter, +1 from Weapon Focus, and +1 from the weapon enchantment = +10. The damage is strength + weapon enchantment + dagger damage = 1d4+4.

They could alternatively (signaled by the **or**) make two attacks, one with the +1 dagger **and** one with the masterwork dagger. Because they have two-weapon fighting in their "Feats" section, they only take a −2 on attacks with light weapons, giving the +8 on the main hand and the damage stays the same.

The offhand attack is a little odd to me. It is made with a masterwork dagger so the damage is just 1/2 strength + dagger damage = 1d4+1. However, a masterwork dagger still provides a +1 to attack so I am unsure where the −1 comes from to make it a +7.

Comment: Using markdown headers (# or ## or ###) is favorable to using bold text for accessibility reasons, I've gone ahead and changed your header.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually 3 listed
+1 dagger +10 (1d4+4 plus poison), or +1 dagger +8 (1d4+4 plus poison) and masterwork dagger +7 (1d4+1 plus poison)

If you look down in "other gear" located at the bottom of the stat block, in it is listed a +1 dagger. Which is why the entries have +1 dagger, and the other is masterwork dagger.

Next we have the +10, the +8, and the +7. These are the total bonuses being applied to the attack roll.

First we have the standard attack which uses the standard action.

- weapon focus (dagger) feat +1
- BAB +5
- magical dagger +1
- strength +3

Then we have the two weapon fighting attack which makes use of the TWF feat and light weapons.

- weapon focus (dagger) feat +1
- BAB +5
- magical dagger +1 in primary hand
- masterwork dagger in offhand (which should be +1)
- strength +3
- two weapon fighting primary -2 offhand -2

It looks like there is a problem with the TWF attack as both should be +8 to the attack roll, as masterwork doesnt apply to the damage, or I have missed something which causes the offhand to be less.